# CLion: Macros for "Working Directory" in External Tools do not resolve

Tags: intellij-idea, rust, clion

Trying to setup an external tool in CLion (run `cargo fmt` before a build).

In "Working Directory" I tried to set:
- `$FileDir$`
- `$ContentRoot$`
- `$ProjectFileDir$`

and testing with a `pwd` command. Every time I can see that the working director is set to `/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin`

No issue if I set "Working directory" as the absolute path to my project folder

Is that a CLion bug or am I missing something?